# Inserting a value to a sublist in a list. PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublist

This piece of code is from a tic tac toe game I am making. I have to insert a value into a sublist in a list. This is my attempt at doing just that, but it does not work (Python 3.5.1). Is it possible to use `insert()` to insert a value into a sublist, if so, how do you do it?

```
game_board_lst = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]] 

play1_row = int(input("Player 1: What row? "))

play1_col = int(input("Player 1: What column? "))

game_board_lst.insert((play1_row - 1)(play1_col - 1), 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the subscript operator `lst[index]`.

Since you have a list of lists, you would use `lst[row][col]`:

```
>>> game_board_lst = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> game_board_lst[1][1]=3
>>> game_board_lst
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, I think you would want to modify an existing value, such as:

```
game_board_lst[play1_row-1][play1_col-1] = 1
```